# ServiceStack - Switch off Snapshot

Tags: servicestack, snapshot

I've followed instructions on how creating a ServiceStack here at:

https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Create-your-first-webservice

I'm sure I have followed it to the letter, but as soon as I run the web application. I get a 'Snapshot' view of my response. I understand this happens when I don't have a default view/webpage. I set up the project as a ASP.net website, not a ASP.net MVC website. Could that be the problem?

[image: Snapshot]

I also wrote a test console application with the following C# code. It got the response as a HTML webpage rather than as a plain string e.g. "Hello, John".

```
static void sendHello()
        {
            string contents = "john";
            string url = "http://localhost:51450/hello/";

            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            request.Method = "POST";
            request.ContentLength = contents.Length;
            request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

            // SEND TO WEBSERVICE
            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
            {
                writer.Write(contents);
            }

            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

            string result = string.Empty;

            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                result = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }

            Console.WriteLine(result);
        }
```

How can I switch off the 'snapshot' view? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The browser is requesting html so ServiceStack is returning the html snapshot.

There are a couple of ways to stop the snapshot view:

- First is to use the [ServiceClient](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/C#-client) classes provided by servicestack. These also have the advantage of doing automatic routing and strongly typing the response DTOs.
- Next way would be to set the `Accept` header of the request to something like `application/json` or `application/xml` which would serialize the response into json or xml respectively. This is what the ServiceClients do internally

```
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    request.Accept = "application/json";
    ...
```

- Another method would be to add a query string parameter called `format` and set it to `json` or `xml`

```
    string url = "http://localhost:51450/hello/?format=json";
```

Comment: It was the Accept I had to set. I can't believe I missed it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Putting the specific format requesting is the practical way to do this

```
string url = "http://localhost:51450/hello/?format=json";
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest simply deleting this feature.

```
public override void Configure(Container container)
{
    //...
    this.Plugins.RemoveAll(p => p is ServiceStack.Formats.HtmlFormat);
    //...
}
```

Now all requests with the **Content-Type=text/html** will be ignored.